# Why TeamCoty build fails? sh: 1: eslint.js: not found

Tags: javascript, teamcity

My logs show Build problem

```
Step 2/7: Node.js
11:50:49 
  Docker wrapper: setting permissions for '/mnt/agent/temp/buildTmp' and '/mnt/agent/work/3198f31b395ddd96' to 1777
11:50:49 
  Running step within container node:lts
11:50:49 
  Container wrapper: prepare reusable container
11:50:50 
  Container wrapper: exec settings
11:50:50 
  Starting: /bin/sh -c . /mnt/agent/temp/agentTmp/docker-wrapper-631609348017899132.sh && docker exec -w /mnt/agent/work/3198f31b395ddd96/frontend 3fd96eb8b1121cb96c534666a399c71a3865cb9a5221dfab2c1c71672c03b4bf /bin/sh -c /mnt/agent/temp/agentTmp/docker-shell-script-9020234573338178042.sh
11:50:50 
  in directory: /mnt/agent/work/3198f31b395ddd96/frontend
11:50:50 
  Container event: {"status":"exec_create: /bin/sh -c /mnt/agent/temp/agentTmp/docker-shell-script-9020234573338178042.sh","id":"3fd96eb8b1121cb96c534666a399c71a3865cb9a5221dfab2c1c71672c03b4bf","from":"node:lts","Type":"container","Action":"exec_create: /bin/sh -c /mnt/agent/temp/agentTmp/docker-shell-script-9020234573338178042.sh","Actor":{"ID":"3fd96eb8b1121cb96c534666a399c71a3865cb9a5221dfab2c1c71672c03b4bf","Attributes":{"execID":"70db919f9fd957f4a6960ce7eded854404a0b108596f065ebb79b2f0a9add059","image":"node:lts","jetbrains.teamcity.buildId":"109","name":"elegant_mirzakhani"}},"scope":"local","time":1699703450,"timeNano":1699703450191405125}
11:50:50 
  Container event: {"status":"exec_start: /bin/sh -c /mnt/agent/temp/agentTmp/docker-shell-script-9020234573338178042.sh","id":"3fd96eb8b1121cb96c534666a399c71a3865cb9a5221dfab2c1c71672c03b4bf","from":"node:lts","Type":"container","Action":"exec_start: /bin/sh -c /mnt/agent/temp/agentTmp/docker-shell-script-9020234573338178042.sh","Actor":{"ID":"3fd96eb8b1121cb96c534666a399c71a3865cb9a5221dfab2c1c71672c03b4bf","Attributes":{"execID":"70db919f9fd957f4a6960ce7eded854404a0b108596f065ebb79b2f0a9add059","image":"node:lts","jetbrains.teamcity.buildId":"109","name":"elegant_mirzakhani"}},"scope":"local","time":1699703450,"timeNano":1699703450191955373}
11:50:55 
  npm WARN deprecated eslint-teamcity@4.0.0: eslint-teamcity has been renamed to eslint-formatter-teamcity
  To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
11:52:54 
    npm audit fix --force 
11:52:55 
  > frontend@1.0.0 lint
11:52:55 
  > eslint.js --format ./node_modules/eslint-teamcity/index.js
11:52:55 
  sh: 1: eslint.js: not found
11:52:55 
  Container event: {"status":"exec_die","id":"3fd96eb8b1121cb96c534666a399c71a3865cb9a5221dfab2c1c71672c03b4bf","from":"node:lts","Type":"container","Action":"exec_die","Actor":{"ID":"3fd96eb8b1121cb96c534666a399c71a3865cb9a5221dfab2c1c71672c03b4bf","Attributes":{"execID":"70db919f9fd957f4a6960ce7eded854404a0b108596f065ebb79b2f0a9add059","exitCode":"127","image":"node:lts","jetbrains.teamcity.buildId":"109","name":"elegant_mirzakhani"}},"scope":"local","time":1699703575,"timeNano":1699703575196714334}
11:52:55 
  Process exited with code 127
11:52:55 
  Node.js: npm WARN deprecated eslint-teamcity@4.0.0: eslint-teamcity has been renamed to eslint-formatter-teamcity
```

Step 2 shell script

```
npm install eslint-teamcity --no-save
npm run lint -- --format ./node_modules/eslint-teamcity/index.js
```

This is my repo

```
https://github.com/MilenkoMarkovic/fastreact
```

What should I change?